# Jquery two scripts undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I keep getting an error saying my jquery is undefined, I have two jquery scripts one called MobileStepOneViewModel.js and another called MobileStepOne.js.

Code for MobileStepOneViewModel.js:

```
var mobileStep1ViewModel = {
IsMobileQueryButton: "#btnIsMobileQuery",
MobileConfirmDiv: ".MobileConfirm",
MobileQueryRadioButton: "#IsMobileQuery",

HideMobileConfirm: function () {
    var selected = $(this.MobileQueryRadioButton).val();
    if (selected == "No") {
        $(this.MobileConfirmDiv).hide();
    }

},
ShowMobileConfirm: function () {
    $(this.MobileConfirmDiv).show();
}
 }
```

Code for MobileStepOne.js:

```
$(function () {
$(MobileStepOneViewModel.IsMobileQueryButton).change(function () {
   MobileStepOneViewModel.HideMobileConfirm();
});
});
```

When I run the page I get an error saying MobileStepOneViewModel is undefined?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Use correct case `"mobileStep1ViewModel" !== "MobileStepOneViewModel"`

Answer (score 0):

I ever seen `MobileStepOneViewModel` in the above code . Use mobileStep1ViewModel instead of MobileStepOneViewModel. Beacuse you declare the object has  mobileStep1ViewModel .

```
$(mobileStep1ViewModel.IsMobileQueryButton).change(function () {
   mobileStep1ViewModel.HideMobileConfirm();
});
```